# alternative for nested for loops for faster run time

Tags: vba, performance, loops

I have a nested for loop that first runs through 10-15k rows, compares a cell in that row to another table that is 40k+ rows, if it finds a match, it returns that match, otherwise "no record" is written in a cell. the code works fine, just investigating an alternative approach to make it run faster. currently, 13000 lines takes about 50 min to an hour to run. I've looked into arrays, but loading an array with 40k+ items seems like the wrong route to take. the report is often run bits at a time, so when it is first created it may have 2k rows, then 3k rows may be added to it later, the code below will skip over rows it has already checked and pick up where it left off. any help is appreciated

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Cells(i, 83).Value <> "" Then GoTo NextIteration:
    Sheets("mft Rpt").Cells(i, 83) = "No Record"
    model = Sheets("MFT RPT").Cells(i, 11).Value
    trimModel = Replace(Replace(model, " ", ""), "-", "")
    For j = 1 To lastCollateralRow
        If trimModel = Sheets("Promosheet Table").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            Sheets("MFT RPT").Cells(i, 83) = Sheets("promosheet Table").Cells(j, 3).Value
        End If
    Next j
NextIteration:
Next i
```

Comment: Instead of that inner `for` loop use [`Range.Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) it's like a million times quicker for finding a match inside of a range. If you are really stuck on that inner `for` loop then use an `exit for` after setting `Cells(i,83)` value so it will bounce out to the next iteration.

Comment: "oading an array with 40k+ items seems like the wrong route to take" - did you actually try doing it or do you just seem to think so without any real data to support it?

Comment: Working with arrays is much faster. In the code below the first part is almost instantaneous. The second one takes ages.

Sub ReadRange()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim arr As Variant

    Set rng = Range("A1:A50000")
    arr = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)

    For a = 1 To 50000
        arr(a) = Rnd
    Next

    MsgBox "End"

    For a = 1 To 50000
        Cells(a, 1) = Rnd
    Next

    MsgBox "End"

End Sub

Comment: @MichalRosa sorry I should have clarified, I did try an array first, and gave up before actually compiling it successfully. I am not too familiar with how they operate but have used them successfully in the past on a much smaller scale. the table referenced during the 2nd forLoop is over 40k rows currently but is ever growing, I was just worried that 40k + would overload it and cause it to run even slower

Comment: also @MichalRosa I don't quite understand your code suggestion above. what is the 'Rnd" variable. what does transposing the array do?

Comment: It's just an example.  RND is not a variable, it's a function.  The example just shows that filling a 50000 spaces array with a random variable is almost instantaneous while filling cells with the same function takes for ages.  Just read the ranges into array, perform your calculations directly on the arrays and print the output.  It's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

This ia just a proof of concept, you will need to adjust variables and ranges to suit your needs.

```
Sub ProofOfConcept()

    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim rngMatch As Range

    Dim arrList As Variant
    Dim arrMatch As Variant

    Set rngList = Range("A1:A50000")
    arrList = Application.Transpose(rngList.Value)

    Set rngMatch = Range("C1:D15000")
    arrMatch = Application.Transpose(rngMatch.Value)

    For a = 1 To 15000
        For b = 1 To 50000
            If arrMatch(1, a) = arrList(b) Then
                arrMatch(2, a) = "Match found"
                GoTo skip
            End If
        Next
skip:
    Next

    rngMatch = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrMatch)




End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Michal

played with it a bit. I trimmed down the run time from almost an hour to about 7 or 8 min using this code. works beautifully!!

```
Dim promoList As Range
Dim rngMatch As Range
Dim arrList As Variant
Dim arrMatch As Variant
Dim z


Set promoList = Sheets("promosheet table").Range("A1:A" & lastcollateralRow)
arrList = Application.Transpose(promoList.Value)
Set rngMatch = Sheets("Mft rpt").Range("K2:K" & lastRow)
arrMatch = Application.Transpose(rngMatch.Value)
For z = LBound(arrMatch) To UBound(arrMatch)
    arrMatch(z) = Replace(Replace(arrMatch(z), " ", ""), "-", "")
Next

For A = 1 To lastRow
    If Cells(A + 1, 83).Value <> "" Then GoTo skip:
    Sheets("mft rpt").Cells(A + 1, 83) = "No Record"
    For b = 1 To lastcollateralRow + 1
        If arrMatch(A) = promoList(b) Then
            Sheets("mft rpt").Cells(A + 1, 83) = promoList(b, 3)
            GoTo skip
        End If
    Next
skip:
Next
```